# Matplotlib 3D drawed surface plot dissapears when user rotates plot and remains only axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Im Ploting 3D surface plot and when user starts to interacting with plot (rotating) drawed plot dissapears and i need to redraw whole plot. How can i keep drawed plot from erasing ?

Here is how i draw plot:

```
workspace = Visualizer.fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

workspace.plot_surface(xv, yv, MatrixToUseInPrint, antialiased=False, cmap=cm.Spectral)
```

[Before rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Lnp.png) [After rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Y7d.png)

Comment: That should not happen. Do you have the same problem with the examples in this [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)?

Comment: Yes ,i tried the same examples and they always dissapear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its cause problem with old version of matplotlib using `plt.show()` helps